# Eclipse: Java Content Assist Advanced tab empty

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

Since today I receive the error "no complementations available", when trying to complete statements in java using ctrl + space.

Quick research made me go to the java editor preferences. I performed a restore defaults both in the tab "content assist" and "advanced".

I guess the problem is, that in the advanced tab both tables are empty. I am unable to tick any points like "Java proposals" as I should be able to.

I did also reinstall eclipse and created a new workspace.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: here´s the log file:
[log.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yiCqiMS76h6Ar9KcT2XfJivkRY5u89-Z)

Comment: Maybe you use a too old version of Eclipse with Code Recommenders. If you can reproduce this issue with an up-to-date Eclipse version (Eclipse 2020-03) and a fresh workspace, please add the content of the `<workspace>/.metadata/.log` file to your question.

Comment: @howlger I have the latest version of Eclipse installed. The content of the log-file is now attached to the question.